# Java, converting non latin UTF-8 characters to proper string

Tags: java, encoding

When I try to output string in Java like this:

```
System.output.println("Привет");
```

Console output shows me this result:

```
Привет
```

I have a REST API method where I receive string from outside request. When I send exact same `Привет` string with UTF-8 encoding and try to output it like this:

```
post("/check", (req, res) -> {
    receivedString = req.body();
}

System.ouput.println(receivedString);
```

It shows this:

```
������
```

What I need to do in order to turn this questionmark thing into proper readable string?

Comment: Looking in stackoverflow, i found any what can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567208/how-can-i-change-the-standard-out-to-utf-8-in-java/42957623

Comment: @AL thanks for help, but these answers are trightly coupled into output stream which is not very useful, because I want to use this string in some other operations.

Comment: “I have a REST API method where I receive string” … Edit your question and show that method’s signature, and the code that obtains the String from the request.  I suspect the code is assuming the wrong charset.

Comment: @VGR Added method how I get string

Comment: Use the debugger to check whether `receivedString` is correct or not. This will tell you if the problem is on the input (POST request) or output side. If you are on Windows, do not trust standard output (`System.out`). It is unlikely that it is configured to handle UTF-8.

Comment: What is the type of `req`?  What class defines the `post` method?

Answer (score -2):

You can try with ...

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(receivedString);
```