# How can I print Vietnamese in the terminal in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

This is my code:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Tiếng Việt có dấu");
  }
}
```

In the VS Code terminal it prints:

```
Ti?ng Vi?t có d?u
```

How can I fix it so the VS Code terminal displays the text correctly?

Comment: I believe that this may be the behavior with VS Code itself rather than Java.  Please try changing your locale/language in VS Code to Vietnamese (follow these steps https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales, please note there is not currently a Vietnamese locale officially supported, but maybe another language shares a character set/alphabet).

Comment: yes, i think something wrong at VS Code, i just use java to show for you, Before, I used VS but they still print in Vietnamese but now they don't, I don't know where they are wrong, im use Python they work but Java and C not

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows >= 10:

1. <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, `intl.cpl`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. doing this:

> [image]

3. Restarting system.

[See here/Thank You!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/592355)

---

Then (after Restart) we try this in VS Code:

```java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println("1: Tiếng Việt có dấu");
    try ( PrintWriter consoleOut = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
      consoleOut.println("2: Tiếng Việt có dấu");
    }
  }
}
```

[See also/Thank You!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28567536/592355)

(Ensuring):

[image: VS-Code, File Encoding, UTF-8]

[See Also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30082741/592355).

---

... we get (Run Java, default shell, pwsh.7.2.0 in my case):

```bash
PowerShell 7.2.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\DEV\projects\test>  & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin\java.exe' '-cp' 'C:\Users\xerx\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_16pw9c0xw9lhctexolmzuqrp.jar' 'Test' 
1: Ti?ng Vi?t c d?u
2: Tiếng Việt có dấu
PS C:\DEV\projects\test>
```

... but also switching to `cmd.exe`:

```bash
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\DEV\projects\test>java -cp C:\Users\xerx\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_16pw9c0xw9lhctexolmzuqrp.jar Test 
1: Ti?ng Vi?t c d?u
2: Tiếng Việt có dấu
```

GitBash?!? - "Null Problemo":

```bash
picard@enterprise MINGW64 /c/DEV/projects/test (main)
$ java -cp ~/AppData/Local/Temp/cp_16pw9c0xw9lhctexolmzuqrp.jar Test
1: Ti?ng Vi?t c d?u
2: Tiếng Việt có dấu
```

So the problem is rather not in VS Code or Java, but more "general"/historic/"proprietary" (see the threads linked + [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1259084/592355) + https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+console+encoding :)

Because in Ubuntu ([wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)) Shell:

```bash
picard@enterprise:/mnt/c/DEV/projects/test$ java -cp ./build/classes/java/main/ Test
1: Tiếng Việt có dấu
2: Tiếng Việt có dấu
```

**!!** ;)