Groovy cyrillic characters output problem
I have a problem with output in groovy script. For example this code:
def rusAlphabet = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ'
def lowerCaseRusAlphabet = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцшщъыьэюя'

println(rusAlphabet)
println(rusAlphabet.toLowerCase())
println(lowerCaseRusAlphabet)

prints:
AБВГДЕ?ЖЗИЙКЛМ?ОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
a??
абвгдеёжзийклмнопр?туфхцшщъыь?ю?

It works fine with Python scripts. I work on Windows 10 x64.
In CMD and PowerShell cyrillic characters were displayed as questions. Then I checked "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in region administrative settings. Now it works fine, characters are displayed normally. But not for groovy scripts.
Tried this code in script:
try {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new InternalError("VM does not support mandatory encoding UTF-8");
}

It prints:
AÐ‘Ð’Ð“Ð”Ð•Ð�Ð–Ð—Ð˜Ð™ÐšÐ›ÐœÐ�ÐžÐŸÐ Ð¡Ð¢Ð£Ð¤Ð¥Ð¦Ð§Ð¨Ð©ÐªÐ«Ð¬Ð­Ð®Ð¯
að‘ð’ð“ð”ð•ð�ð–ð—ð˜ð™ðšð›ðœð�ðžðÿð ð¡ð¢ð£ð¤ð¥ð¦ð§ð¨ð©ðªð«ð¬ð­ð®ð¯
Ð°Ð±Ð²Ð³Ð´ÐµÑ‘Ð¶Ð·Ð¸Ð¹ÐºÐ»Ð¼Ð½Ð¾Ð¿Ñ€Ñ�Ñ‚ÑƒÑ„Ñ…Ñ†ÑˆÑ‰ÑŠÑ‹ÑŒÑ�ÑŽÑ�


https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957623/238704

with this code i get
AÐ‘Ð’Ð“Ð”Ð•Ð�Ð–Ð—Ð˜Ð™ÐšÐ›ÐœÐ�ÐžÐŸÐ Ð¡Ð¢Ð£Ð¤Ð¥Ð¦Ð§Ð¨Ð©ÐªÐ«Ð¬Ð­Ð®Ð¯
að‘ð’ð“ð”ð•ð�ð–ð—ð˜ð™ðšð›ðœð�ðžðÿð ð¡ð¢ð£ð¤ð¥ð¦ð§ð¨ð©ðªð«ð¬ð­ð®ð¯
Ð°Ð±Ð²Ð³Ð´ÐµÑ‘Ð¶Ð·Ð¸Ð¹ÐºÐ»Ð¼Ð½Ð¾Ð¿Ñ€Ñ�Ñ‚ÑƒÑ„Ñ…Ñ†ÑˆÑ‰ÑŠÑ‹ÑŒÑ�ÑŽÑ�

You don't have any answers yet, so edit your question to show the code where you tried the idea in that answer. The console/terminal being used to run the program may also be significant.

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'AБВГД'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252') returns 'AÐ‘Ð’Ð“Ð”' (used merely a short substring). As a side note: you use  A (U+0041,  Latin Capital Letter A) and a (U+0061,  Latin Small Letter A) instead of  А (U+0410,  Cyrillic Capital Letter A) and а (U+0430,  Cyrillic Small Letter A), respectively.

I use cyrillic letters А and а. Problem is not just in these letters, you can see Ё, Н, с, э and я interpreted incorrectly

I'm sure that there is Latin A in def rusAlphabet = 'A. In def lowerCaseRusAlphabet = 'а is truly Cyrillic а, sorry. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].


I would have expected your activation of system-wide support for UTF-8 (Windows code page 65001) to solve your problem, because it sets both the OEM and the ANSI code page to 65001, which should make all legacy (non-Unicode) programs "speak UTF-8".

Note that activating this feature - while convenient - has far-reaching consequences and can break legacy code: see this answer for background information.

If you do not use this feature, the following is required in addition to ensuring that source code is read as UTF-8 (see next major point):

As shown in this answer mentioned in the comments, you must switch stdout and stderr (the standard output and standard error streams) to UTF-8:[1]
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, "UTF-8"));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err), true, "UTF-8"));


You also need the execute the following to make a PowerShell session use UTF-8 consistently (see this answer for background information):
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding






Your problem implies that Groovy doesn't interpret your source code file (script file) as UTF-8 but rather as Windows-1252, which is the ANSI code page for the US-English locale as well as many European ones.

Groovy, perhaps needless to say, is based on Java, and Java versions 17 and below use the system's ANSI code page to interpret source code files, whereas v18+ commendably uses UTF-8. As such, with the ANSI code page being 65001, i.e. UTF-8, this shouldn't be a problem - but perhaps Java determines what the active ANSI code page is differently.

However, irrespective of whether you've activated system-wide UTF-8 support, you can explicitly instruct Groovy / Java to interpret source code as UTF-8, as follows:

groovy `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 <your-Groovy-script>

Note the ` before -, which is only necessary when calling from PowerShell, due to an unfortunate bug - see GitHub issue #6291.


Alternatively, you can preset this option via the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable (e.g., from PowerShell, for the current process:
$env:JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8'), though note that the Groovy CLI will then print a message indicating use of the environment variable.







[1] Note: I'm unclear on how to also switch stdin (the standard input stream) to UTF-8 for text-based operations; do tell us if you know.

Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, Dfile.encoding doesn't help either. It shows just all questions instead of characters.

Understood, @mabes. The only way I get only ? characters in the display output is if system-wide UTF-8 is not in effect and System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, "UTF-8")); is not used in the script. What does [Console]::OutputEncoding.WebName report on your system? Also, what is your Java version? (& (Join-Path $env:JAVA_HOME\bin java) --version

I am so sorry, I really forgot that I've commented System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, "UTF-8")); line. With this it works fine.

No worries, @mabes, thanks for accepting. I've updated the answer to show the System.setOut() calls for when UTF-8 isn't turned on system-wide. If you happen to know how do the same thing for stdin (standard input), please let us know.
